# He has been a victim of fraud

Tags: present-perfect, adjective-phrases, noun-phrases

1. He has been a victim of fraud.
2. He has been a victim of fraud *on several occasions*.
3. He has been very helpful.
4. He has been very helpful *on several occasions*.

What is the difference between (1) and (2), (3) and (4)?

Here I'm trying to understand the difference between "has been + **noun**" and "has been + **adjective**". Do they work the same way?

I know that "has been + adj" indicates a state. But does that state necessarily start at a earlier point in time and end now? Can it refer to a state or a period of time that ended in the past and not "now"?

What about "has been +noun"? Does it also indicate a state/a period of time? Or does it refer to a point in time?

Comment: I can't see how it's relevant that all these examples start with ***He has been*** rather than ***He was***. Please either explain why you think the Perfect form makes a difference here, or consider editing so the examples are no more complex than they need to be to illustrate whatever aspect of usage is being queried.

Comment: edited.........

Comment: ***He has been sick*** implies greater ***relevance*** to time of utterance than ***He was sick***, but it doesn't *necessarily* imply anything about the past state/action continuing ***up until*** time of speaking. Nor without additional context can we infer anything regarding whether ***to be sick*** means ***to be unwell*** or ***to vomit*** (and that ambiguity would *still* apply with *He has been / was sick **on several occasions***).

Comment: 1 and 3 indicate it happened one time but leave open whether it happened more than one time.  2 and 4 indicate it happened more than one time. Is this not clear?

Comment: Whether something happens multiple times or when it happened is driven by the verb, not the adjective or the noun. Has been is past perfect, so that sets up your timeframe.  Consider "He has been very helpful." An example might go like this: The police officer asked the mother, "Did you son help you after the fire?" "Yes sir. He has been very helpful."